# How to add multiple web application in single solution and run both at same time

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add 2 MVC web application in single Solution, in Visual Studio.

How can i add and how to run both project in single start click or is there any way to start 1 application and it's start other one....

Please give me some idea or solution,

Answer (score 4):

If you right click the solution and then select "Multiple Startup Projects" you can tick which projects you want to start after build.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adil Z's solution, if you need for them to be built in a particular order (if that's what you mean by "is there any way to start 1 application and it's start other one") you can specify build order by right clicking on one of the projects, selecting "Project Dependencies"->"Build Order" from the context menu.